# Docker containers suddenly stop seeing each other

Tags: docker

I have tow containers : one for my app and one for the database.

Every thing works find since weeks until today : the app container can't reach the db one anymore, this is the error message :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

After reading [this post](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-fails-to-perform-name-resolution/2655/6) I've restarted the docker service and then every thing worked fine !

How can I find what's wrong so I can prevent such problems ?